# No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation

Tags: java, spring, jpa

So I'm trying to extend a repository for some custom implementation. The code was working before when I had:

```
repositoryBaseClass = AccountRepositoryImpl.class
```

in the PGConfig.java class, but now multiple custom implementations have to be made and I can't have multiple repositoryBaseClass classes defined.

So when I run just a basic test, I'm getting this exception:

log:

```
...
Caused by: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'JpaEntityInformation<?, ?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I tried to follow the example laid out here: [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-method-in-all-repositories)
But I'm trying to deviate from it because I need another implementation class for a different repository.

I've tried multiple different things including adding @Autorwired to the EntityInformation member variable, but that didn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if what I'm doing is possible?

Both the repositories and impl java files are in the same directory

PGConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  transactionManagerRef = "postgresTransactionManager",
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresEntityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = {"org.user.domain"}
  repositoryImplementationPostfix="Impl")
...
```

AccountRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends AccountRepositoryCustom<Account, Long> {
  Optional<Account> findById(String id);

  @Override
  List<Account> findAllById(Iterable<Long> ids, Sort sort);
}
```

AccountRepositoryCustom.java

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AccountRepositoryCustom<E, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<E, I> {
  Page<I> findAllAccounts(Specification<E> specification, Pageable pageable);

  Page<I> findAllAccounts(Pageable pageable);

  List<E> findAllById(Iterable<I> ids, Sort sort);
}
```

AccountRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class AccountRepositoryImpl<E, I extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<E, I> implements AccountRepositoryCustom<E, I> {
  private final JpaEntityInformation<E, I> entityInformation;
  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  public AccountRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<E, I> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  @Override
  public Page<I> findAllAccounts(Specification<E> specification, Pageable pageable) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(entityInformation.getIdType());

    ...
  }

  @Override
  public Page<I> findAllAccounts(Pageable pageable) {
    return findAllUserAccounts(null, pageable);
  }

  @Override
  public List<E> findAllById(Iterable<I> ids, Sort sort) {
    ...
  }
}
```